# How to show multiple camera angles together in a Multicam clip in FCPX?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, multi-camera

So I've been able to combine two different clips shot by two different cameras at different angles at the same time by creating Multicam clip and choose to sync by sound.

However, when I try to edit this multicam clip, it seems that I could only choose to show one camera clip at a time. **I want my two clips to show side by side, like**

[image]

I know to do that in a normally created project, we can just put two clips together in the timeline and edit transformations for both clips from "Transform" in here

[image]

But how can I do the similar thing to a multicam clip?

Maybe from here? (Seems that in here I can only choose to switch between angles at different timeline but not show both angels at the same time)
[image]

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is mark the edit points for the clip where you want the effect to appear. Then highlight the edited clip so that it is highlighted in yellow.
Now copy that clip by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Now menu over the clip and select “Lift from storyline”.

You will now have an empty grey clip on the Storyline.

Click on that Grey clip and paste the copy of the original clip on to it.
Go back to the start of the clip and then change the angle of the clip on the storyline.

Finally, change the size of the two clips to give the side by side effect.
Dependent on you snap options you may need to drag the clips back together to the right places, when you paste the duplicated clip onto the stroryline.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I just wanted to clarify that you have to blade the multicam clip at the start and end (not just a range selection) where you want to do PiP or show angles side by side. Then copy it, lift it from the storyline, and then you can paste and rearrange angles.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not what Multicam clips are for, quite the opposite. Multicam clips are designed for showing only one angle out of multiple source angles. 
Did you try an synchronized clip instead? When the synchronization is done you can double click the clip and transform the individual clips to fit your screen.

Comment: Synchronized clips are great for when you want to do this for a longer period, but I have a case where I have three camera angles, and for a long video I normally just switch between them (which is super easy using the Angles display to switch angles). There's just one spot in the middle I want to display them PiP, so @Paul Middleton's answer was helpful to let me do just that.